# How to get a TCP socket with CSD data call bearer on Windows Mobile 5.0?

Tags: windows-mobile, dial-up

I'm writing a mobile application which needs to connect to a server using dial-up ( CSD ) connection. An additional request is that it needs to use TCP over PPP ( the server is using such combination ).

I know how to get the CSD connection using RAS API. But what I'm asking is how to get a TCP socket that "uses" this connection underneath.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up the connection in the settings | connection settings applet, and choose modem instead of gprs/cellular/bluetooth, then use connnection manager to initiate that connection. That will create a tcp/ip connection over csd, and you should just be able to open a socket in your code to the right ip address...